# Error loading cx_Oracle module with IIS and PyISAPIe

Tags: django, iis-6, cx-oracle, pyisapie

I have developed a Django application, and i am
trying to get it to run under IIS on Windows Server 2003. I'm
generally following [the Django walkthrough](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer) but my db is Oracle.

If I run python from the command prompt and import `cx_Oracle`, it works
just fine. If I run the project with django's development server, everything works fine too.
I haven't managed to get it rum on IIS6 but when a `test.py` is loaded by IIS and
`PyISAPIe`, it says it cannot load `cx_Oracle` and displays the following
error:

> Error loading cx_Oracle module: DLL load failed: The specified module
>   could not be found.

I'm using the 32-bit versions of the following:

```
Python 2.6.6,
PyISAPIe 1.1.0 rc4 py2.6,
Django 1.4.3,
Oracle Client 11.2, 
cx_Oracle 5.1 (for Oracle 11g, Python 2.6)
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

EDIT:I tried downgrading to cx_Oracle 4.4.1 and now I get the error:
     ImportError: cannot import name utils

Comment: Could be an issue with paths?

Comment: @Rickard Zachrisson I downgraded to cx_Oracle 4.4.1, fixed the paths and it worked. But when I try to get it work with cx_Oracle 5.1 I still get the first error message related to the DLL.